# Copying data from file to table

Tags: php, html

I'm attempting to copy data from a file, create a new file, copy the contents from this table, place it in a table and output it. However, after browsing and selecting a file, the only output in my table is the path of the file.

I've also attempted to copy and paste the contents into the new file I created. However, my code just clears it and places only the path in the file.

Any hints?

```
<?php
$Semester = $_POST['Semester'];
$CourseID = $_POST['CourseID'];
$SectionID = $_POST['SectionID'];
$file = $_POST['SelectFile'];
echo "You entered:".$Semester.",".$CourseID."&".$SectionID.".";

if (file_exists($file)){ 
    echo "The file ".$file." exists.";
    }
    else {
    echo "The file ".$file."does not exist.";
    }

    file_put_contents("hw3data_server.txt" , $file);
        //copy('$file','hw3data_server.txt');
    $myfile = fopen("hw3data_server.txt","r") or die ("Unable to return file.");
 ?>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>Student Name</th>
    <th>Course Grade</th>
    </tr>

    <?php



    while(($row = fgets($myfile)) != false) {
    echo "<tr>";
    $col = explode("\n",$row);

    foreach($col as $data) {
            echo "<td>". trim($data)."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>

</table>
</body>
</html>



<form method="post" action="hw3_grade_form.php">
<h3>Please submit semester (e.g., Spring 2018), course ID (e.g., BCS 350),
Section ID (e.g., 21695), and upload a text file that includes all student names.</h3><br />
Semester: <input type="text" name="Semester" value="" /><br />
Course ID: <input type="text" name="CourseID" value="" /><br />
Section ID: <input type="text" name="SectionID" value="" /><br />
Select File: <input type="file" name="SelectFile" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: What? what do you think this does `file_put_contents("hw3data_server.txt" , $file);`,  I think it writes that file with just the filename in it.  So `my code just clears it and places only the path in the file.`  Surprising?  `$file = $_POST['SelectFile'];`

Comment: `int file_put_contents ( string $filename , mixed $data [, int $flags = 0 [, resource $context ]] )`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: And this `//copy('$file','hw3data_server.txt');` which is the right way to copy it, except that the name of the file is not `'$file'` which is the word `$file` literally.  Single quotes and double quotes do 2 different things.

Comment: One more thing. In order to upload files from form, you will need to specify enctype. <form method="post" action="hw3_grade_form.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Answer (score 2):

AS I said in the comments.  But lets look at your code.

```
$file = $_POST['SelectFile'];
file_put_contents("hw3data_server.txt" , $file);
```

> int file_put_contents ( string $filename , mixed $data [, int $flags = 0 [, resource $context ]] )

`$file` is the name of your file. the second argument of `file_put_contents` is the data, so you put the filename in the data of the file.  Which surprise surprise creates a file with the filename in it.

Now the bit you commented out.

```
//copy('$file','hw3data_server.txt');
```

This is the correct way to copy a file, but you are using `'$file'` with single quotes which does no variable interpolation (doesn't put the value of a variable in place)  So you try to copy a file with the name of `$file` literally, not with the value of `$file` which is the filename.

Instead try `copy($file,'hw3data_server.txt');`

Without the single quotes.

This logic is flawed

```
if (file_exists($file)){ 
   echo "The file ".$file." exists.";
}else {
   echo "The file ".$file."does not exist.";
}

file_put_contents("hw3data_server.txt" , $file);
```

See checking is good and all fine, but then you just go and do it anyway. Say that `if` condition fails what's to prevent running `file_put_contents`.  Nothing, you echo the error then proceed to execute it.

```
 do{
    if (file_exists($file)){ 
       echo "The file ".$file." exists.";
    }else {
      echo "The file ".$file."does not exist.";
      break; //exit doWhile
    }

    if(!@copy($file, "hw3data_server.txt"){
       echo "Failed to copy the file ".$file;
       break; //exit doWhile
    }

    //rest of code...

 }while(false);
```

See the the Do While loop, works a bit different then a while loop.  A while loop checks the condition then runs, a do while loop runs 1 time, then checks the condition.  So this loop runs only 1 time as the condition is false.

So why use it.

Well it lets us take advantage of using `break` which will exit a loop.

So because this is all procedural, no classes no functions, the only way to control the execution flow is by nesting the if conditions in such a way that we exclude chunks of code we don't want to run.

But, we can just use this little trick and break out of the loop and stop running whenever we want.

**Update**
*I thought this used existing files, not a http upload form, thanks to @Omar Tanti for pointing that out.*

Because this is a HTTP upload form you have to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag.  It has something to do with how the data is passed ot the server, I don't care to get into the specifics of that though, just trust me it wont work without it.

```
<form method="post" action="hw3_grade_form.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

Now that we fixed that, instead of using `$_POST['SelectFile']` you'll need to use `$_FILES['SelectFile']['tmp_name']`.  There is some other important stuff in `$_FILES` so I would do a quick `echo '<pre>'; var_export($_FILES);` to check out the details of that.

Last thing is you really should not be moving and copying a upload file this way, you should use

[move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

> bool **move_uploaded_file** ( string **$filename** , string **$destination** )
>
> This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism). If the file is valid, it will be moved to the filename given by destination.
>
> This sort of check is especially important if there is any chance that anything done with uploaded files could reveal their contents to the user, or even to other users on the same system.

For various security reasons. Basically, this checks that the file was uploaded which mitigates some directory traversal attacks.  This type of attack uses the filename to point to a file on the server which then could be output and shown to the attacker (or at least that's how I understand it).

An example would be uploading a file with a name constructed to mimic the location of `wp-config.php`. Such as a file named `../../wp-config.php` This file has Database user and password information in it (for wordpress). The `../` is navigate up one directory level.  So the server could navigate up two levels and pull that file instead. Then if you read out the contents of the "uploaded" file in your code without checking if it was actually an uploaded file.  This could trick the server into reading out the contents of that file and showing it to the "attacker" thereby giving them credentials to the server etc. (this is probably a poor example, but the best I could think of off the top of my head).

In other words this is pretty much a complete mess.

I would suggest looking into some basic file upload tutorials as they can cover the process of building a file upload far better then can be handled here.  Also this type of "tutorial" is far outside the scope of the Q&A format of SO.

That said, you can pretty much replace the `copy` in my code above with  `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['SelectFile']['tmp_name'],"hw3data_server.txt")`  And that should at least get you started.  But it's worth reading up on for some of the security considerations I mentioned above.

Sorry this is so long and rambling.